# Winston logging file rotation :: On rotation the new file's owner is inconsistent (Sometimes it is the user, sometimes it is root)

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm running into a frustrating problem that was a little hard to track down.
I have a background process (node CRON job controlled by pm2) that was trouble-free until a few months ago and then suddenly it developed the following error...

`EACCES: permission denied, open '../logs/textract-prod/default-2023-06-07.log'`

Once this error occurs the process enters a failed state.  It is controlled by pm2, which will restart the process, but as soon as it tries to log to the file (which it does on startup) it encounters the permission problem and it crashes, and gets restarted again.

Once it gets in this state I have to manually fix it, by either changing the file owner, or deleting the current log file and restarting the process.

I should mention at this point that I am running the process in user space, and the log directory is in the user's home directory.

- User: `bigbird`
- Log directory: `/home/bigbird/logs/textract-prod/`
- OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`

For logging we use the winston package and the winston-daily-rotate-file package.

- "winston": "^3.8.2"
- "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1"

Loggers are configured like this:

```
new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
  filename: `${config.LOG_PATH}/${logFileName}-%DATE%.log`,
  datePattern: "YYYY-MM-DD",
  zippedArchive: true,
  format: combine(timestamp(), formatForFile),
  level: (options.LOG_LEVEL_FILE || config.LOG_LEVEL_FILE),
};
```

Looking at the logs I noticed a pattern: the file permission problem always starts at midnight UTC.  Which led me to the log file rotator.

I confirmed this theory by checking the file permissions of a set of files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird    12782 Jun  1 00:00 default-2023-05-31.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     170817 Jun  2 00:00 default-2023-06-01.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird     5983 Jun  3 00:00 default-2023-06-02.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       8034 Jun  4 00:00 default-2023-06-03.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird     3349 Jun  5 00:00 default-2023-06-04.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     144375 Jun  6 00:00 default-2023-06-05.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       3332 Jun  7 00:00 default-2023-06-06.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     359175 Jun  7 20:52 default-2023-06-07.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird       20 Jun  2 00:00 exceptions-2023-05-31.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird 23026509 Jun  2 23:59 exceptions-2023-06-02.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird       20 Jun  4 00:00 exceptions-2023-06-03.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird   761161 Jun  5 00:00 exceptions-2023-06-04.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird      505 Jun  6 00:00 exceptions-2023-06-05.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird 23029489 Jun  6 23:59 exceptions-2023-06-06.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird       10 Jun  7 00:00 exceptions-2023-06-06.log.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigbird bigbird 18453511 Jun  7 19:13 exceptions-2023-06-07.log
```

So straight away I see the rotator has a random chance of creating the new log file with the current user as the owner, but sometimes `root` is the owner.

What the ____ ?!

Why would this be random?  This only happens for one node-cron-job process and only on production.  My solution has about 8 of these background cron jobs and they all share the same logging code.  Only one of them has this problem, and only in production.

THIS affected cron job is probably the busiest, so perhaps that is why it's the only one that exhibits the problem. Perhaps they ALL have a random chance of messing up the file ownership on rotation and it shows up for this cron job because it is busier.

Another thing that is special (but not unique) about this cron job is that we spawn some python processes from it.  We capture the stdout and stderr from those processes in the parent process and write that to the log.  I'm wondering if that has something to do with why we sometimes get a root-owner log file.

```
const child_process = require("child_process");
const defaultLogger = require("./logger");

const pythonRunner = {
  spawnPython3Process : async(pythonScript, processCounter, ...args) => {
    try{
      args.unshift(pythonScript); // Add the script to the beginning of the array.
      defaultLogger.info(`parallel processes = ${++processCounter.count}`);
      const pyProcess = child_process.spawn("python3", args);
      pyProcess.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
        const output = data.toString();
        if (output.startsWith('INFO:'))
          defaultLogger.info(`python > ${output.substring(5).trim()}`);
        else if (output.startsWith('ERROR:'))
          defaultLogger.error(`python > ${output.substring(6).trim()}`);
        else if (output.startsWith('WARN:'))
          defaultLogger.error(`python > ${output.substring(5).trim()}`);
      });
      pyProcess.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
        defaultLogger.error(`python > ${data.toString()}`);
      });
      pyProcess.on('close', (code) => {
        defaultLogger.info(`parallel processes = ${--processCounter.count}`);
      });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      defaultLogger.error(`Fatal error spawning python3 script => ${pythonScript}`);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = pythonRunner;
```

The reason I don't think THIS is the problem:

1. We are doing the logging back in the main process, which is running in user space.
2. `child_process.spawn` should be creating processes in the same user-space as the parent process.

***Note:** I have verified this by logging the uid and gid of the process in both the host process as well as in the `pyProcess.stdout.on("data"` event handler.*

PS. I have also posted this issue on the package's GitHub repo, but the repo is not highly active. https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file/issues/374